# Html Indentation

Tags: code-golf

Given an inconsistently indented piece of html code your task is to return the same text but correctly indented

- Indent space = 4
- Assume input will be non-empty.
- Input can be taken as string or array/list of lines
- Opening and closing tags must be on the same line as long as there is not any other tag inside. `<td></td>`
- Assume there will be only html tags, no text elements whatsoever
- All opening tags that aren't self-closing will have closing tags, and will be given in the correct nesting order. Self-closing tags will be closed with `/>`
- Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply

**Example and test-cases**

```
Input
--------------
<table>
     <tr>
  <td>
</td>
      <td></td></tr></table> 

Output
----------
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

```
Input
------------
<div>
              <ul>
<li></li><li></li></ul>
        <ul>
              <li></li>
<li></li>
</ul><div><table>

<tbody>
  <thead>
 <tr>
        <th></th>
          <th></th>
             </tr>
       </thead>
   <tbody>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></tbody></table>
       </div>
</div>

Output
--------------------
<div>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
Input
--------------
<div><img src=""/><p></p><input/><input/></div>

Output
-------------
<div>
    <img src=""/>
    <p></p>
    <input/>
    <input/>
</div>
```

Comment: Do we need to support single-label tags like `img` or `a`?

Comment: @AdmBorkBork Yes

Comment: Then how should `<p><p></p>` be indented? Like `<p>\n<p></p>` or `<p>\n    <p>\n</p>`?

Comment: `<p><p></p>` is valid HTML (tag soup). Are you confusing HTML with XML?

Comment: By specifying HTML I'm assuming that you do not care about significant whitespace? `<foo></foo>` can be meaningfully different than `<foo>\n</foo>` if we're just talking about XML in general.

Comment: Also worth noting that xmllint can probably be used to trivialize this problem.

Comment: <p><p></p> is not valid Xhtml.

Comment: @edc65: This question is not about xhtml

Comment: @recursive yes I kwow. Maybe the OP does not

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz You can add a rule "Each tag that is not self-closing has a matching (open/close) tag", regarding `<p><p></p>`.

Comment: I voted that this question should remain closed. It still needs clarification in the challenge description about text nodes and whitespace.

Comment: One could do that problem for general indentation that gets string as "(" or "{" for open the correspondence for close... it seems to me something one can handle with one little recursive function...

Comment: Apologies to you all. I'll edit the question right now to make it more clear

Comment: Do we need to consider `<input type=text value="you_guess" onclick=f("2'3'4"); disabled />`?

Comment: `<div id={br}""></div>`

Comment: @l4m2 no.......

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I'd make a note that all tags are guaranteed to match `/\w( (\w*="\w*"))*/` or something. Maybe more lax than `\w` in `"\w*"` but that's up to you

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz May we split self-closing tags into an opening and a closing tag?

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 101 bytes

```
L`<.*?>
T`¶`_`<(.+)¶</\1
^.+
$&/
{`(( *)((?!.*(</|/>)))?.+)/¶(.+)
$1¶$2$#3*4* $5/
    (</.+>/)
$1
/$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVDBasMwDL3rKzJqiu2ARbb2Jpwf2HHHsTnFgQbCBsUtlO678gH5scyKWeqWHqaD9Cy992T70Ibuq6mm6dWR0bWFNzcO7tORNKUaB8L3Cj5MCWKNcHFSFlpJWT8ZLQl/0Cql6kjEcWA@iGocxLNYveiNLsQWoYgRmaa0yFNAAdNEvjvZeXQNOvYWqO8sIacFIPdvSHe6PyZkiEXzEgrNrm8tAIXdtz@zmMK@bXxEFA6Zc9hHcUyZ/aMetzET8jzZMT/tWIwpeDbw96fk8F8aJtuspjctN5h/M5Vf) Explanation:

```
L`<.*?>
```

List just the tags.

```
T`¶`_`<(.+)¶</\1
```

Join matching pairs of tags.

```
^.+
$&/
```

Add a marker to the end of the first line.

```
{`(( *)((?!.*(</|/>)))?.+)/¶(.+)
$1¶$2$#3*4* $5/
```

Copy the indentation from each line to the next, adding 4 spaces if the current line is an opening tag.

```
    (</.+>/)
$1
```

But if the next line (which is now the current line) is a closing tag then delete 4 spaces.

```
/$
```

Delete the marker once it reaches the last line.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 170 bytes

```python
def f(o,i=-4):
 s,c,n,h,l=" <\n  "
 for t in"".join(o.split()).split(c):
	if'/'==t[:1]:i-=4;h+=(n+i*s)*(l!=t[1:])+c+t
	else:h+=n+i*s+c+t;i+=4-4*('/'in t);l=t
 print h[4:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVDLbsMgEDyHr6BcAn7ESuQTBv9I6kNibEGFwLK3lfL1Ltit5UQ9lMPuMrMzCzs8QHt3mWfV9binPjMyLxlHeMrazGU6s5Jg8e4wJgj3fsSAjSPk9OGNo/40DdYAZeynaIPyYPpjcZQSrvzccJPLstKppC41ycQSat8Cc@YNS9sU0KGzU8cDv9ARqkwqy7xMaDAxDgOrrASEh9E4wPpa8mbuKSFEKPNVI/x0xKetkbCmFkUMW1FE/KnpRffbiXZVFC1DBNzutqsREnD36hHFAnR3U6ESMO6cQQdxCDv7v7AIFzth5Fe72L/O2IwFqGigXm@rw3/bitV2l9c/bS9YtrmmsFw2fwM)

Comment: This removes the space between `img` and `src` in `<img src="hey"/>`

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 174 bytes

```python
import re
def F(I):
 m=x=0
 n,s,b='\n/<'
 for d in re.findall(r'<(.*?>)',I):
	if d[0]==s:print(n+' '*~-m*4)*x+b+d,;m-=1;x=1
	else:print n+' '*m*4+b+d,;x*=s in d;m+=not s in d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZFNbsMgEIXX4RQjb/ybkFRdxeDuIvUMbRd2wTUSYAuTytn06i4U1XWiLmKJmWH43gPMcLFdrx/mWaihNxYMR4y3cEqe0yMCRSe6R6CLsWho/KoxiRG0vQEGQjt21wrNaikTE5Nklz1VaVx44Ua0wF72b5SOx8EIbROdxxBnX1uVPabZlDc5K0q1pYdyoge04XLkAYQAOiwwU0ZHvxcrVU51byHM5lMSRRFh4rMKQagPGM07jSJckaEi2A2hh7PFfxl7EsHVR86yQkQKt@rDUmDfv4JudL8kWlVeFI5j60byCiFim55dvJjYjtfMVcSalbPtnNiFlf1/Pd/GK6FfD3aeD3ssxsQyb8BuZ8HhXgwH21UOd1pO8PM3Q3Jvkc7f)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript 115 Bytes

```
s=>(n=c=-1,m=f=>"\n"+" ".repeat(4*c)+f,s.replace(/<\/?|\/>/g,w=>w[1]?(n?k=m(w):k=w,n=1,c--,k):m(w,n=0*c++)).trim())
```

I lost the original code so whoops no explanation on this one. It's short though so think of it as a reversing challenge :)

Adds some newlines, but it is correctly tabbed.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 141bytes

```php
preg_match_all("%(<.*>)%U",$argn,$m);foreach($m[1]as$t)echo!$p|($p=$t[1]!="/")?str_pad("\n",($t[-2]!="/"?$p?++$i:$i--:$i+!$p=0)*4-3):!$i--,$t;
```

Run as pipe with `-nR` or [try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/abe368d34ca1f4f67d3fe52839aedb04dc2356cf).